# How to convert a vector of string into vector of integers in R?

Tags: r, vector, integer, character

I have a vector string which looks like this

```
A <- c("162&u", "139&u", "87&us", "175&u", "54&us", "25&us", "46&us","16650", "16776", "16689", "16844")
```

How do I convert it into  a vector of numeric arrays that looks like this in R?

```
 A <- c(162,139,87, 175, 54,25,46,16650, 16776, 16689, 16844)
```

Comment: You can just `as.integer(gsub(pattern = "[^[:digit:]]", "", A))`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A generalized approach:

```
as.numeric(gsub("\\D+", "", A))
#[1]   162   139    87   175    54    25    46 16650 16776 16689 16844
```

Comment: Can you please explain what the pattern "\\D+" means?

Comment: See this cheat sheet and the Character Classes portion http://www.cheatography.com/davechild/cheat-sheets/regular-expressions/

Comment: It matches anything that is not a digit

Answer (score 0):

```
B <- as.numeric(gsub("&.*","",A))
```